# How to request REST API correctly for GET & DELETE without resources ID?

Tags: rest, api, http-get, http-delete

Please let me know if I misunderstanding.

Getting all active users

> **GET** /api/users?**active**

What if I want to get all active user's messages

> **GET** /api/users/**active**/messages

Or what if I want to delete all active user's messages

> **DELETE** /api/users/**no-active**/messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to request REST API correctly for GET & DELETE without resources ID?

From the perspective of REST, this question doesn't make a lot of sense.  Any named information can be a [resource](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1), and we use the resource identifier (aka, the URI) to identify which resource we are talking about.

```
GET /api/users?active
```

In this query, `/api/users?active` is a resource identifier (what RFC 7230 refers to as the [request-target](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.3) expressed in origin form).

Your resource, in this case is "all active users", or perhaps more precisely "the list of all active users"; the representation of that list will change over time depending on which users are currently active.

```
GET /api/users/active/messages
```

Same idea here, the resource is the list of messages.

Now normally when we are trying to modify a resource, we use the identifier of the resource as the target-uri for the change.  So modifications to the list of messages would all share a common target-uri

```
POST /api/users/active/messages
PUT /api/users/active/messages
PATCH /api/users/active/messages
DELETE /api/users/active/messages
```

This is because the URI serves as a cache key, and general-purpose components that are familiar with HTTP caching semantics will know to [invalidate](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4) any previously cached representations of the resource.

In HTTP, [DELETE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.5) has a precise semantic meaning, which is to remove the association between the identifier and its representations.  The natural consequence of a successful DELETE is that a subsequent GET would return a [404 Not Found](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.4) (which means that the requested target-uri has no current representation).

If what you are intending is to modify the representation, then POST/PUT/PATCH are the more natural choices.

```
PUT /api/users/active/messages
Content-Type: application/json

[]
```

is a message that means "replace your current representation with this one".

Replacing one representation with another is pretty trivial when your implementation is just a document store - you validate the incoming representation, and then overwrite the old representation with the new.  With dynamically generated representations, supporting the same semantics is a lot more work.

It may ease your life considerably to POST a "delete all messages" request to the resource, rather than trying to PUT a new representation.

Comment: What if I want to delete all users that inactive && registered_at < 2019 && age < 20, What URI should look like ? DELETE /api/users/....

Answer (score 1):

Different methods can have same route:
Delete (**DELETE**) can still be the same:

```
DELETE /api/users/active/messages
```